# ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER happening on ReadFile() on Win10 but not Win7

Tags: c++

I am trying to read low-level data on an SD card. I run as administrator and use the following code to open the device:

```cpp
hDrive = CreateFile(StrDeviceCode.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

`StrDeviceCode` is typically `"\\\\.\\HarddiskVolume5"` or similar (I also try `"\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive5"` or similar. Be assured that I know this is the device I want).

On Win7 this works, but on Win10 it does not - I get a valid handle but `ReadFile()` returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

I've read all the questions related to `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` on `ReadFile()`, where the answers range from making sure alignment to sector-size to other tweaks on `CreateFile()`.

I am using the same external USB card reader and SD card. I try reading a wide variety of lengths, always multiples of 512, mostly 512 and 4096. So I've got all that covered.

I tried many different file flags, like `FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH`, `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`, but nothing works.

Is there something Win10 threw into the mix that I'm missing?

Comment: So, you have written a lot of words and shown nothing about using ReadFile.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are trying to read from the device that is not working for you.

Comment: wstring StrDeviceCode = "\\\\.\\HarddiskVolume5";
int hDrive = CreateFile(StrDeviceCode.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
int BytesReadWIN = 0; 
unsigned char* = new unsigned char[512];
int err = ReadFile(hDrive, buf, 512, (LPDWORD)&BytesReadWIN, NULL);

Comment: This is not really directly reproducible, you have to substitute numbers relevant to your system.

Answer (score 0):

[CreateFileA function (fileapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea?redirectedfrom=MSDN#physical_disks_and_volumes)

**Physical Disks and Volumes**

Direct access to the disk or to a volume is restricted. For more information, see "Changes to the file system and to the storage stack to restrict direct disk access and direct volume access in Windows Vista and in Windows Server 2008" in the Help and Support Knowledge Base at https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/942448 (the original page is not available at
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942448).

You may match the device path with drive letter using the [Volume Management Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/volume-management-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: This doesn't really seem to answer the question? Linking to changes made in vista seems unlikely to be relevant for a program that broke on upgrade from Windows 7 to 10?

Comment: The symptoms described by OP exactly match that above. CreateFile works and returns a handle for DeviceIoControl, but ReadFile fails with invalid parameter error if used with this handle. I don't know about Windows 7, perhaps these restrictions are optional there or dependent on a filesystem.

Comment: I did try everything AFAIK in that article. I will also add that most/all of the time the SD card does not have a readable file system to it and doesn't have a drive letter. I am reading a foreign file system that Windows knows nothing about.